# How to set custom color on stacked bar chart

Tags: jquery, charts, highcharts

I want to below type of stacked column chart.
Is it possible to draft this kind of chart?

Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can enable `colorByPoint` option for the last series:

```
  series: [..., {
    ...,
    colorByPoint: true
  }]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fdwbLzan/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.colorByPoint

---

or define an individual color for each point:

```
  series: [..., {
    ...,
    data: [{
      y: 3,
      color: 'black'
    }, {
      y: 4,
      color: 'purple'
    }, {
      y: 4,
      color: 'green'
    }, {
      y: 2,
      color: 'orange'
    }, {
      y: 5,
      color: 'blue'
    }]
  }]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/r87mv6n3/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.data.color

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Your code in above is only display the chart in bar chart.
But I Want to display my own custom color on stacked bar chart for all rows.

Comment: Hi @Rackymuthu, What do you exactly mean? In the live example, the chart seems to look the same as in your picture.